# Expand MSBuild property containing the name of other property

Tags: msbuild

Let's say I have property `$(Foo)`, that is defined as a result of some function, that returns the string value `$(Bar)`. Is it possible to expand it somehow, so that `$(Foo)` will be expanded to the value of `$(Bar)`?

Given example project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <Bar>Bar Value</Bar>
        <Foo>$([System.String]::Concat("$(","Bar",")"))</Foo>
        <Baz>$(Foo)</Baz>
        <Qux>$(Bar)</Qux>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Target Name="Test">
        <Message Text="Foo == $(Foo)" />
        <Message Text="Baz == $(Baz)" />
        <Message Text="Qux == $(Qux)" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Here's what I have:

```
S:\>msbuild Test.proj /t:Test /nologo                 
Build started 18.09.2013 17:52:14.                    
Project "S:\Test.proj" on node 1 (Test target(s)).    
Test:                                                 
  Foo == $(Bar)                                       
  Baz == $(Bar)                                       
  Qux == Bar Value                                    
Done Building Project "S:\Test.proj" (Test target(s)).


Build succeeded.                                      
    0 Warning(s)                                      
    0 Error(s)
```

So, `$(Qux)`, which is defined to `$(Bar)` directly, is expanded correctly, but `$(Foo)` and `$(Baz)` are not. Is it possible to expand them too?

```
S:\>msbuild /version                                     
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.0.30319.17929       
[Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.18052]      
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

4.0.30319.17929
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to simulate something like $($(Foo)) that is invalid syntax for MsBuild. But you can simulate this behavior by using items and by dynamically creating items in targets. You can’t do it in the *"global scope"* because of [Property and Item evaluation order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997067.aspx#sectionToggle4).

So you have to do it in some targets.
Here is sample that sets property by means of `InitialTargets`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project InitialTargets="MyPropertiesSetup" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

<PropertyGroup>
    <Bar>Bar Value</Bar>
    <!-- A value of Foo property specifies the name of the property it takes value from. -->
    <Foo>Bar</Foo>
    <Baz></Baz>
    <Qux>$(Bar)</Qux>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="Test">
    <Message Text="Foo == $(Foo)" />
    <Message Text="Baz == $(Baz)" />
    <Message Text="Qux == $(Qux)" />
</Target>

<Target Name="MyPropertiesSetup">
    <ItemGroup>
        <_Foo Include="$(Foo)" />
        <_Baz Include="%(_Foo.Identity)" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <Foo>$(%(_Foo.Identity))</Foo>
        <Baz>$(%(_Baz.Identity))</Baz>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Target>

</Project>
```

If you can use item for values instead properties, there is more elegant way do it  ([MSBuild Trickery](http://www.k7ranch.net/Trickery) #68 - @($(CanYouDoThis)):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

<PropertyGroup>
    <Foo>Bar</Foo>
    <Foo2>Bar2</Foo2>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
   <Bar Include="Bar Value" />
   <Bar2 Include="Bar2 Value" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="Test">
    <Message Text="Foo == '@($(Foo))'" />
    <Message Text="Foo2 == '@($(Foo2))'" />
</Target>

</Project>
```